# No content on wordpress dashboard page after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a plugin, but somehow when I post a form and redirect back to the page, the page is empty. Content returns after a page reload.

I use the following after the (successful) form submit.

```
wp_redirect(get_permalink());
exit();
```

I don't seem to get any errors (I do have WP_DEBUG on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be cache in your browser or web server. You can try generate unique link for reload. For example add to url parameter.

```
$url = add_query_arg("unique", time(), get_permalink());
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```